# Using the OpenSSL libraries built from source in an OS X app

Tags: macos, openssl

My OS X app uses the OpenSSL libraries, both the libssl and libcrypto libraries. The specific version of OpenSSL libraries it has been using is the one provided in OS X, namely `/usr/lib/libssl.dylib` and `/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib` and currently at version OpenSSL 0.9.8zg, and my app has been working fine.

Since I want to use TLS 1.2 in my app, and the OpenSSL libraries provided in OS X, at version OpenSSL 0.9.8zg, do not support it, I want to use the OpenSSL libraries at version OpenSSL 1.0.2d, available in source at the OpenSSL site, in my app.

Toward the goal of upgrading the OpenSSL libraries in my app to version OpenSSL 1.0.2d, I built the OpenSSL libraries from source and compiled my app with them successfully. However, the resulting app didn't function properly, and I don't know why. Running the resulting app, SSL_connect() always returned an error, and the subsequent call to SSL_get_error() always returned SSL_ERROR_SSL. This was the case for the libraries being dynamic libraries or static libraries. More strangely, I got the same result when I used OpenSSL 0.9.8zg libraries built from the source in building my app.

Anyone have a solution or explanation to the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was actually no problem in the OpenSSL libraries I built. The problem I encountered was caused by a cert. For some reason, the problem only occurred when the new version of OpenSSL was used. Replacing the cert removed the problem.